# Can roles access included role attributes?

Tags: raku

I have a class that does a role that does another role.  A method from the class can access an attribute in the top level role:

```
role A {
    has $.x
}

role B does A {
}

class C does B {
    method this() { say $!x }
}

C.new(:x(1)).this;
```

That works fine and says 1 like I think it should.

But I have a number of classes that all do role B, that I want to share the method this(), so I move it up into role B:

```
role A {
    has $.x
}

role B does A {
    method this() { $!x }
}

class C does B {}

C.new(:x(1)).this;
```

That won't even compile: `SORRY Attribute $!x not declared in role B`.

Can a role not see attributes in a role it includes?

Comment: It does work with `$.x` using the accessor method -- I'm just wondering why it can't see the attribute without that.  I'm guessing because the final composing of all the roles doesn't happen until the class is defined.

Comment: Yes, that's what I think is the problem.  Patches welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing this requires the introduction of a private method in the first role and access through that:

```
role A {
    has $.x;
    method !x() { $!x }
}

role B does A {
    method this() { self!x }
}

class C does B {}

say C.new(:x(1)).this;  # 1
```

The reason the original code doesn't work - and isn't trivial to make it work - is that roles are generic and potentially overloaded with different sets of type parameters, so the mention of a role is itself generic. Therefore, in general, the `does A` does not identify a specific target role; there could be multiple of them, and they could have different attributes. It's not until the point that we compose the role into a class that we finally identify the concrete set of roles being composed.

However, attribute accesses are a kind of variable access, and so checked at the point we are compiling the role. In the final class, this isn't so much of a problem, since we are at that point choosing all the concrete roles we'll use; this is why it can easily work there. For the `role` case, we couldn't really check them until the point of composition into a final class, which could be in a separate compilation unit altogether. This is likely a solvable problem, and a future Perl 6 language version could specify a way for this to work. For now, it conservatively does not.